# Keep absolute positioned elements in same position on different resolutions

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I'm facing a frustrating problem with absolute positioned elements moving when viewed on different screen resolutions.

My elements are positioned with percentages against the body element. Surely using percentages would keep elements in same position?

my page:  http://www.superfreebingo.com/advent-landing/

How can I use absolute positioning but keep elements in same place on different resolutions?

Comment: Well, use px instead of %?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a graphic scene like the one you're trying to build needs to have each element at a given coordenate for it to make visual sense, so depending on what you want:

**Fixed scene**: Giving the body element a fixed size will result in a fixed scene (the percentages used to position elements will always be the same), although smaller screens than the scene will be missing out on the full thing.

**Responsive scene**: As each element must have a given relative coordenate, it's no use using only horizontal or vertical positioning, as they only account for one of both numbers for a coordinate. Also, you must account for image sizing, as a tablet will need to see a smaller version of the scene than a desktop.

It's tricky but not impossible, I would recommend you start off with a fixed scene and then try and add responsiveness to it, either using JS to calculate the scene size (width will always be 100%, height has to be calculated) or the "transform: scale(...)" css property.

Comment: I think I will try fixed size to begin with, didn't think of applying width to body tag itself